# Explicit modified midpoint (Gragg smoothing)

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-difference-method, stiffness

In the "StifnessSwitching" method the default numerical scheme for the non-stiff solver is Explicit modified midpoint (Gragg smoothing) with a decreasing step size.

I decided to study the stability properties of this method from scratch. However, I can't find the finite difference scheme of the Explicit modified midpoint method that is used in "StifnessSwitching" in the help manual. Can anyone put this scheme down?

Comment: Bear with us. What _Mathematica_ method are you talking about? Do you have a particular problem in mind (and in code)?

Comment: I am talking about the "StifnessSwitching" method. No particular problem, just a general question. What is the finite differential scheme of the explicit solver that is used in the "StifnessSwitching" method by default? 

In the help is stated, that it is the Explicit modified midpoint method. I do know the scheme of the Explicit midpoint method. However, I do not understand what kind of modification is applied to it.

Comment: Have you read ["StiffnessSwitching" Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessSwitching.html) and [Stiffness Detection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html)?

Comment: Yes, but there is no formulas for the used scheme.

Comment: What about ["Extrapolation" Method for NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExtrapolation.html), namely the subsection [Gragg's Smoothing Step](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExtrapolation.html#1940172755)?